# In Stylus, do I have to write nested selector from its root when @extend?

Tags: stylus

Stylus returns 'Failed to @extend ".selector2" ', but it's OK in SASS.

```
.selector1
    color #000
    .selector2
        color #FFF
    .selector3
        @extend .selector2
```

It's OK when I write selectors from root in Stylus.

```
.selector1
    color #000
    .selector2
        color #FFF
    .selector3
        @extend .selector1 .selector2
```

But it's quite troublesome.

Is there any way to write Stylus same as SASS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, You can't write Stylus @extend same as SASS. But I can suggest alternatives:

**1.** we can simply use the `@` character to get the value of the nearest `color`

```
.selector1
    color #000
    .selector2
        color #FFF
    .selector3
        color @color
```

**2** Extending placeholder selectors

```
$foo
  color: #FFF
.selector1
    color #000
    .selector2
        @extends $foo
    .selector3
        @extends $foo
```